# Transmission rate of PS/2

Tags: usb, ps2

USB 2.0 full speed - **12 Mbps**

USB 2.0 high speed - **480 Mbps**

But what are the rates for PS/2?

Answer (score 6):

**Controller**

```
Port / Device           Typical Data Transfer Rate
```

**Super I/O**

```
PS/2 (keyboard / mouse) 2 KB/s
Serial Port             25 KB/s
Floppy Disk             125 KB/s
Parallel Port           200 KB/s
```

**Southbridge**

```
Integrated Audio        1 MB/s
Integrated LAN          12 MB/s
USB                     60 MB/s
Integrated Video        133 MB/s
IDE (HDD, DVD)          133 MB/s
SATA (HDD, DVD)         300 MB/s
```

I found [here](http://www.cci-compeng.com/Unit_5_PC_Architecture/5509_IO_Bus.htm). Maybe obsolete but can use as a reference point.

Comment: That cant be right I think. 2 kb/s vs 60 mb/s, it seems wrong. Are keyboards affected by those low PS/2 rates?